# Dompdf library: can I store files to hard disk?

Tags: php, dompdf

i'm using dompdf library to render some html content into pdf files.

I actually don't need to send the file back to the client but just to store it in the hard disk or even better to send an email with it as attachment.

I've searched in the documentation but I could only find the stream method:
http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/usage.php#methodstream

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file',$dompdf->output());
```